# Send an Excel worksheet in the body of an email

Tags: c#, html, excel, email

I would like to send an Excel worksheet to a mailing list while preserving as much of the formatting as possible.  If you are aware of a way to do this I would much appreciate it.

The Excel workbook contains many sheets, but only one is designed and formatted to be emailed.  The sheet contains cell references, filters, and conditional formatting.

I have experimented with using Gembox to convert the Excel worksheet into HTML (with `ExcelFile.Save(worksheet, HtmlSaveOptions.HtmlDefault);`) and sending that but I have run into a few limitations:

1. The dynamic Excel content (i.e. cell references) isn't calculated until the workbook is opened in Excel and then saved.  This is a problem because the workbook is created in C# and often not saved again by the user.
2. Conditional formatting does not appear when converting to HTML this way.

Comment: Google is your friend.

Comment: I haven't found anything on sending the content in the email body.  Can you provide the search result that you are referring to?

Comment: Most email services, notably Gmail, will parse and change much of the HTML and styling needs to be inline.  You can probably get a table to mimic the look and feel but it will be nowhere close to excel if it is in the body of an email.  You'll have a lot more success with an attachment.

Comment: It would be sent across the Microsoft exchange so all recipients should see the same content.  It sounds like what I want is impossible (aside from what I've come up with) based on what I'm hearing.

Comment: Send a screenshot to preserve the formatting, and, if needed, send the real worksheet or workbook as an attachment.

Comment: For the first point, you need to call `ExcelFile.Calculate` method. For the second point, you need to use the current latest version of GemBox.Spreadsheet, it has support for exporting conditional formatting in output HTML.